# When Clicking on image view it should open that page.....and the video should page

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

So,Basically I have created a listview for this,so whenever in MainActivity1.java code when i will click on the panga image then the panga page should be intended and that video should play.I somehow managed to do the same with bhoot img and it worked.But I dont know How can I do with other movies.

this is my MainActivity1.java code

```
public class MainActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter MovieAdapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    ImageView imageView3;

    String[] movieNameList = {"BHOOT","PANGA","PSYCHO","JUMANJI","DIL BECHARA","BAAGHI 3","THE BRIDGE CURSE","LOST GIRLS","BAD BOYS FOR LIFE",
                              "THAPPAD","SADAK 2","TANHAJI","BHEESHMA" };
    String[] movieDescriptionList = {"Horror/Mystery","Sport/Drama","Thriller/Psychological   Thriller","Comedy/Action","Romance/Drama","Action/Thriller",
                                     "Horror/Thriller","Mystery/Drama","Action/Comedy","Drama","Drama/Thriller","Action/Historical     drama","Romance/Rom-com"};
    String[] movieRatings = {"3.5/5","4.5/5","3/5","4.5/5","4/5","4/5","3.5/5","2.5/5","3/5","5/5","3.5/5","4/5","3/5"};
    int[] movieImages = {R.drawable.bhoot,R.drawable.panga,R.drawable.psycho,R.drawable.jumanji,R.drawable.dil_bechera,R.drawable.baaghi3,R.drawable.bridgecurse,
                          R.drawable.lostgirls,R.drawable.bad_boys,R.drawable.thappad,R.drawable.sadak2,R.drawable.tanhaji,R.drawable.bheeshma};



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainpage);
        recyclerView  = findViewById(R.id.recycleview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        MovieAdapter= new MovieAdapter(this,movieNameList,movieDescriptionList,movieRatings,movieImages);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(MovieAdapter);
    }

    public void IMAGE(View view) {
        ImageView imageView3 =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        imageView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent o = new Intent(MainActivity1.this,BhootVideo.class);
                startActivity(o);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

this is my panga.java code

```
public class panga  extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button play;
    VideoView video1;
    MediaController mediaController;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.panga);

        play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
        video1=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video1);
        mediaController=new MediaController(this);


        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String videopath = "android.resource://com.example.moviebookingapp2/"+R.raw.panga;
                Uri uri=  Uri.parse(videopath);
                video1.setVideoURI(uri);
                video1.setMediaController(mediaController);
                mediaController.setAnchorView(video1);
                video1.start();




            }
        });

    }
}
```

this is panga.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="20sp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:barrierMargin="20sp"
    tools:context=".panga">


    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video1"
        android:layout_width="469dp"
        android:layout_height="196dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/White"
        android:text="PLAY"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Panga"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2020 ‧ Sport/Drama ‧ 2h 11m"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFBFB"
        android:text="An old man with a stick walking try to wake up his neighbourhood, early in the morning. Jaya Nigam .She is having repeatedly abnormal movement during her sleep in which she kicks her husband, Prashant Sachdeva everynight.It is depicted despite having a supportive family she had a dream yet to realise due to being a wife and a mother Adi. Jaya Nigam is a former Kabaddi world champion, never wants to end her passion about the sports.  "
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="19dp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CAST:Kangana Ranaut,
Jassi Gill ,Richa Chadda
Neena Gupta ,Yagya Bhasin, Megha Burman
Rajesh Tailang,
Smita Tambe  "
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:text="SELECT MALL"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is my code foe firstpage.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/LightGrey"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:onClick="IMAGE"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold">

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textSize="20sp">

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Ratings"
            android:textSize="20sp">

        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my code for MovieAdapter,java code

```
public class MovieAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    String[] movieNameList;
    String[] movieDescriptionList;
    String[] movieRatings;
    int[] movieImages;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView rowName;
        TextView rowDescription;
        TextView rowRatings;
        ImageView rowImage;


        public ViewHolder( View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            rowName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            rowDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            rowRatings = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text3);
            rowImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

        }
    }
    public MovieAdapter(Context context,String[] movieNameList,String[] movieDescriptionList,String[] movieRatings,int[] movieImages){
        this.context = context;
        this.movieNameList = movieNameList;
        this.movieDescriptionList = movieDescriptionList;
        this.movieRatings = movieRatings;
        this.movieImages = movieImages;
    }


    @Override
    public MovieAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstpage,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( MovieAdapter. ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.rowName.setText(movieNameList[position]);
        holder.rowDescription.setText(movieDescriptionList[position]);
        holder.rowRatings.setText(movieRatings[position]);
        holder.rowImage.setImageResource(movieImages[position]);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return movieNameList.length;
    }




}
```

Comment: post up movieadapter and activity_main xml too

Comment: YA sure will edit the question

Comment: Attached the code